# javafx setclip gradient mask

Tags: java

how can I use the setClip in javafx as gradient Mask?

```
Pane pane = new Pane();
ImageView iView = new ImageView(new Image("images/img.jpeg"));
pane.getChildren().add(iView);

rMask = new Rectangle(200,250);
rMask.setLayoutX(100);
rMask.setLayoutY(100);

pane.setClip(rMask);
```

Comment: Can you add an image of what you're trying to achieve?